# Let $X$ be a random variable prove that the function $Y$ defined by parts is a random variable

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, random-variables

Let $X$ be a random variable. The function $Y$ is given by

\begin{equation}
Y =  
\begin{cases}
a \ \ \ \ \text{if } X<a \\
X \ \ \ \text{if } a\leq X\leq b \\
b \ \ \ \ \text{if } X>b
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

where $a<b$. I want to prove that $Y$ is a random variable. In order to do this I have to show that for each $y \in \mathbb{R}$ the set $ (Y\leq y) \in \mathbb{F} $, where $\mathbb{F}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra.

**Here's what I have done so far:**

Let $y\in \mathbb{R}$.

**Case 1:** if  $y<a$ then $(Y\leq y) = \emptyset \in \mathbb{F} $

**Case 2:** if $a\leq y \leq b$ then $(Y\leq y) = (Y<a)\cup (a\leq Y \leq y) = \emptyset \cup (a \leq X \leq y) = (a\leq X\leq y) \in \mathbb{F} $.

**Case 3:** if $y>b$ then $(Y\leq y) = \Omega \in \mathbb{F}   $

This implies that $Y$ is a random variable.

**These are my questions:**

1. Is my proof correct?
2. Do you know another way to show that $Y$ is a random variable?

Thanks!

Comment: Your proof is almost correct: in case two you have that $Y \le y$ if and only if $X \le y$. Anyway $(X \le y) \in \Bbb F$, so the proof is the same.